# Erro ao exibir a soma de três arrays lidos

Tags: c, array, int

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int i, notas[5];
    int soma = 0;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)  {
        printf("Digite os tres numeros:\n");
        scanf("%d", &notas[i]);
    }
    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
        soma = soma + notas[i];
        soma = notas[1] + notas [2] + notas[3];
        printf("Valor: %d\n", soma);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Não sei porque não funciona, queria ler três números e exibir, mais a soma, mas não funciona, retorna o tamanho da variável "soma".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu segundo `for` está errado, tente da seguinte maneira:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int i, notas[5];
    int soma = 0;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)  {
        printf("Digite os tres numeros:\n");
        scanf("%d", &notas[i]);
    }
    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
        soma = soma + notas[i];
    }
    printf("Valor: %d\n", soma);
    return 0;
}
```

Para fazer a leitura das 3 notas *inline* (na mesma linha e separado por espaço), terá de fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int i, notas[5];
    int soma = 0;
    printf("Digite os tres numeros: ");
    scanf("%d%d%d", &notas[0], &notas[1], &notas[2]);
    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
        soma = soma + notas[i];
    }
    printf("Valor: %d\n", soma);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Caso, eu queira exibir o valor lido em apenas uma linha, como faço? Por exemplo: inserir 0 2 3, inteiros. ja tentei sem o \n ??

Comment: @Chhh você quer exibir os valores informados pelo usuário e depois a soma deles?

Comment: Sim, sem teclar o "ENTER", inserir os valor com espaço.

Comment: @Chhh editei a resposta para o que você pediu.

Comment: Obrigado, exatamente como eu queria :)

Answer (score 2):

Quando tens

```
for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
    soma = soma + notas[i];
    soma = notas[1] + notas [2] + notas[3];
    printf("Valor: %d\n", soma);
}
```

Estás a dar valores a `soma` de maneira redundante. Ou seja a soma vai sempre ser `notas[1] + notas [2] + notas[3]`, estás a reescrever `soma` em linhas seguidas; e para isso nem precisava de estar dentro do ciclo for.

Se queres ir mostrando a soma à medida que o loop corre deves usar somente:

```
for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
    soma = soma + notas[i];
    printf("Valor: %d\n", soma);
}
```

Se quiseres mostrar só a soma final podes usar:

```
for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
    soma = soma + notas[i];
}
printf("Valor: %d\n", soma);
```

Comment: @renan, não, eu quero somar mesmo..

Comment: Esqueci que os arrays começavam em 0.